# Где в интернете можно учить весь курс по HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT бесплатно?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу создать крутой сайт на html, css, javascript языках, но знание не хватает, хочу учить эти языки, но в интернете полный курс html css java стоит денег, а у меня их нет в данный момент.

Comment: а вы интересно - будете работать Бесплатно ?

Comment: Эм.. Вообще-то везде разбросаны...

Answer (score 2):

Для начала можно на sololearn, а так же на stepik.На developer.mozilla.org можешь так же посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

Я, к примеру, HTML учил на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML), CSS вот по этому учебнику - [тыц](https://idg.net.ua/blog/uchebnik-css), а JS - на [learnJS](https://learn.javascript.ru/).
Лично мне кажется, что, если вы хотите найти курс, где все собрано за вас, то всяко придется платить. Если же бесплатно, то нужно самому собирать информацию. 
Ну и [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn), если нормально с английским.

Answer (score -3):

вообще там 2 пути

1. нужно будет попереводить - открываешь сайт W3C и там ищешь теги ксс и хтмл. жаваскрипт ищешь на сайте жаваскрипт, плюс на W3C есть по жаве теги. Непонятно только на каких условиях они там эту инфу размещают(судя по всему сайты кодить можно, но вот учить языку кого то - не понятно - если твой сайт будет учить хтмл то они могут забрать твои просмотры себе как оплату)

2.вообще все сайты - просто в поисковике ишешь тег или как сделать ххх на хтмл-ксс, просто делаешь то же в текстовике, работает - удаляй лишнее, не работает - и не надо, другие теги есть, разбираться слишком дорого в этом, на жаваскрипт вконтакте не сделать - значит максимум что ты сможешь - сайт "продам гараж", а за рекламу - сколько будет просмотров посчитай - интернет во всем мире не у всех есть, а на ру. вообще мало кто посмотрит твою рекламу, и сколько за нее платят посмотри

3.начать надо с сервака. добавь пустую страницу на сервак с текстом, открой из кафе в макональц - вдруг конретно у тебя нет доступа к интернет(ты в паралельном интернете, и тебя никто не увидит, не услышит, не прочитает ни один твой комент)